# My Code is not returning the value I expect

Tags: c#, string, equals

Hi I recently decided to start learning C#, I made this quick program to get familiar with the way its written.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CSharpTesting
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] Names = new string[4] { "Ben", "Thor", "Zoe", "Kate" };
            Names[0] = "ben";
            Names[1] = "thor";
            Names[2] = "zoe";
            Names[3] = "kate";
            int Max = 4;
            int Current = 0;
            bool Found = false;
            Console.WriteLine("What player are you looking for?");
            string PlayerName = Console.ReadLine();
            while ((Found = false) && (Current <= Max))
            {
                if (Names[Current].Equals(PlayerName))
                {
                    Found = true;
                }else
                {
                    Current++;

                }
                Console.Write(Names[Current] + PlayerName);
            }
            if (Found == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Yes, they have a top score");
                Console.Write(PlayerName);

            }
            else if (Found == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No, they do not have a top score");
                Console.Write(PlayerName);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Every time I run the code it returns "No, they do not have a top score" even when I enter the same string as one of the names in the array. I think the problem may be with the way im checking if the 'PlayerName' and the array Names are the same but im not sure. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Protip: convention in C# is to give local variables (variables declared within a function, and function parameters) `lowerCase` names, not `TitleCase` names, this is to make it easy to tell them apart from type names and public properties.

Comment: I know it won't add any help to your question, but I notised you use if(Found == true) you can short it easy with if(found) it will do practicly the same but it is shorter to write, if you want to check the false condition do if(!found) this will do the same as if(found == false). I hope this will help you on your way of lerning c#.

Comment: @Dai: I like "lower_case" but I'm just an old luddite. Definately agree with using separate styles between Methods/Types and variables (sometimes with a scope prefix).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to Capital Case.

Change the "`Equals`" Method with compare with the ignoreCase

```
if(string.Compare(PlayerName, Names[Current], true) == 0)
```

Anyway as other users said: `Found = false` is wrong. 
You have to write `Found == false`

Comment: Thanks! I fixed the mistakes and it works great now.

Comment: Then you should mark correct answer as best one. This will give reputation and close your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
while ((Found = false) && (Current <= Max))
```

Should be

```
while ((Found == false) && (Current <= Max))
```

By the way, names with a capital letter at the beginning are usually for classes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the if clause to this:

```
if (Names[Current] == PlayerName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your while condition to:

```
while ((Found == false) && (Current <= Max))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(Found = false)
```

is an error. If you need a comparison use ==

```
  (Found == false)
```

= is intented to assign false value to Found variable

All you code can be replaced with

```
if (Names.Contains(PlayerName ) )
```